# Pinning list elements to position in a merged list in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

This seems like a simple scenario, but I'm stumped on how to solve it elegantly/functionally. I have two lists `val pinnedStrings: Seq[(String, Int)]` and `val fillerString: Seq[Int]`. I want to merge them, but with each pinned string guaranteed to be at its paired position in the output list. So if I have:

```
val pinnedStrings = Seq("apple" -> 1, "banana" -> 4, "cherry" -> 6)
val fillerStrings = Seq("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot")
```

Then the output should be:

```
Seq("alpha", "apple", "bravo", "charlie", "banana", "delta", "cherry", "echo", "foxtrot")
```

Let's say that if there's not enough filler to reach a pinned string, we drop the pinned string. (Or if it's simpler to put all leftover pinned strings at the end, that's fine too.)

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
scala> val pinnedStrings = Seq("apple" -> 1, "banana" -> 4, "cherry" -> 6) 
pinnedStrings: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((apple,1), (banana,4), (cherry,6))

scala> val fillerStrings = Seq("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot")
fillerStrings: Seq[String] = List(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo, foxtrot)

scala> (fillerStrings /: pinnedStrings) { case (acc, (s, i)) => ((acc take i) :+ s) ++ (acc drop i) }
res0: Seq[String] = List(alpha, apple, bravo, charlie, banana, delta, cherry, echo, foxtrot)
```

Comment: That's pretty slick! I was working on a `fold`-based solution. This does presume `pinnedStrings` is pre-sorted, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after I'd written up the question, but figured I'd share since I'd already put in the effort:

```
val pinnedStrings = Seq("apple" -> 1, "banana" -> 4, "cherry" -> 6) 
val fillerStrings = Seq("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot") 

// Preadjust the specified indices to account for earlier pinned strings 
val pinnedStringsAdjusted = pinnedStrings.sortBy(_._2).zipWithIndex.map { case ((item, position), index) => (item, position - index) }

// Take advantage of the stability of `sortBy` to give pinned strings priority 
(pinnedStrings ++ fillerStrings.zipWithIndex).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)

// Output
// res5: Seq[String] = List(alpha, apple, bravo, charlie, banana, delta, cherry, echo, foxtrot)
```

Should work as intended for adjacent pinned indices but weird behavior would ensue if two pinned strings have matching indices. Open to other options if other people have thoughts as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if it feels to cumbersome to implement something in terms of existing collection combinators, it suggests trying a direct recursive implementation.

Here's one way:

```
def fill[A](pinned: List[(A, Int)], filler: List[A]): List[A] = {
  def loop(pinned: List[(A, Int)], filler: List[A], i: Int, result: List[A]): List[A] = {
    (pinned, filler) match {
      case ((a, `i`) :: tail, _) => loop(tail.dropWhile(_._2 == i), filler, i + 1, a :: result)
      case (_, (a :: tail))      => loop(pinned, tail, i + 1, a :: result)
      case _                     => result // no filler left
    }
  }
  loop(pinned.sortBy(_._2), filler, 0, Nil).reverse
}

val pinnedStrings = List("apple" -> 1, "apple2" -> 1, "banana" -> 4, "cherry" -> 6)
val fillerStrings = List("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot") 

fill(pinnedStrings, fillerStrings) // List(alpha, apple, bravo, charlie, banana, delta, cherry, echo, foxtrot)
```

Notice that it doesn't need as many passes over the collections.

Comment: Point taken on the performance benefit of fewer passes, but I'm not sure that's more comprehensible than the combinator-based solutions :)

Comment: In fact, I was going to add the current index to my simple fold, but thought I'd want to recurse at that point. TL;MS (too late; must sleep) And spell check wants me to change recurse to recourse. Ha.